# Как устранить ошибку "CSS препятствуют загрузке контента страницы"

Tags: css, django, веб-программирование, pagespeed-insights, cdn

Работаю над оптимизацией сайта. Использую pagespeed от google. Столкнулся с ошибкой

> Некоторые ресурсы препятствуют загрузке контента страницы. Рекомендуем
>   настроить загрузку необходимых ресурсов JS/CSS в первую очередь и
>   отложить загрузку остальных ресурсов.

Вот, что я заметил:

1. Если подключать внутренние стили через onload, то они некорректно подгружаются.

```
<link rel="preload" href="{% static 'assets/landing/css/photobox.css' %}" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

2. Если подключать внешние стили (например, bootstrap через cdn) через onload, то они но подгружаются корректно и рейтинг немного поднимается.

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

3. Если подключать просто через preload (без `onload`) любые стили, то рейт падает и pagespeed выдаёт ошибку.

Как быть в такой ситуации? Загружать стили на cdn?

Ссылка на проверку страницы на pagespeed - https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=RU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fc6f8b145.ngrok.io%2F&tab=mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не критичные стили перенеси в footer. А самые важные, так называемые critical CSS вставь инлайном в head.
В идеале там должны быть только те стили, которые отвечают за каркас страницы. Чтобы когда страница подгрузилась у тебя текст не пролистался вниз. А всё остальное, что отвечает за цвет и так далее, должно подключаться после отрисовки элементов.